# Can't install virt-manager

Tags: virt-manager

When I try to install via terminal using :

```
sudo apt-get install virt-manager
```

I get this message :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package virt-manager
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 64bits

Main and Universe packages are allowed.

Comment: `virt-manager` is located in the main repositories. What distro and version are you using? Have you refreshed the packages list before with `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.04, main repos are also enabled.
Yes, I've updated packages many times.

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy` and the output after running `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: apt-cache policy outputs a long content that I can't add to the post. However, it displays packages URLs that have 500, or 100 before them.
Upate command shows the following errors at the end:


W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucid-bleed/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucid-bleed/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Audit the contents of the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory. If it `apt-cache policy` does not fit in the post, use http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I bought it with pre-installed version (12.04), then upgrade it to 13.04.
apt-cache policy output http://paste.ubuntu.com/6836482/
sources.list content http://paste.ubuntu.com/6836484/
sources.list.d directory content : http://paste.ubuntu.com/6836490/

Comment: I should be able to install after updating
sudo apt-get update Thanks for the support.
Karan

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in 22.04 jammy because `virt-manager` is in `universe`, and I did not have `universe` in my `sources.list.d`.

The solution was to add these two lines (update `jammy` with your release name) to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe restricted
```

[Reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/948cc1/ok_i_give_up_how_do_i_install_qemu/e3j4u44/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need all PPAs. If you install Flash player + Chromium, you can remove the Chrome PPA. By reducing the number of external repositories, your packages list will be refreshed must faster.

Mixing multiple distro versions is a bad idea. You now have both Precise and Raring enabled in your [sources.list](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6836484/). Since Raring is end-of-life since 27 January 2014, the Raring packages will vanish from the main repos soon. You need to replace your hosts by old-releases.ubuntu.com as described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/6969).

Comment: What is a PPA?  How does it relate to "Unable to locate package virt-viewer" ?